# How to use Asset Manager API in NDK to read raw data?

Tags: android-ndk, buffer, android-assetmanager

I have shaders kept in assets folder.
name of the shader (file name) : "vertex.vs"
path : assets/shaders/vertex.vs

I want to access this file from a C++ file from NDK without calling Java or JNI whatever it is.
From reading various resources I managed to understand that i have to use the header

```
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
```

After that I create pointers and open it.

```
const char* mPath = "shaders/vertex.vs";
AAssetManager* mAssetManager;
AAsset* mAsset;
mAsset = AAssetManager_open(mAssetManager, mPath,AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
int foo = AAsset_getLength(mAsset);
LOGD( "This is a number: %d", foo );
AAsset_close(mAsset);
```

But it doesn't do anything.
And what's with this read function.

```
AAsset_read(mAsset,pBuffer,bytesToRead);
```

Where is the data read? How to define the pBuffer ?
Can someone share a simple example on how to read the data from a raw file and how to access it(Like showing it in logcat)?

Comment: _"Where is the data read?"_  Into whatever memory `pBuffer` points to. _"How to define the pBuffer ?"_ You need to pass a pointer to a chunk of memory large enough to fit `bytesToRead` numer of bytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must initialize **mAssetManager** to begin with, we usually get it from Java via a JNI call, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617834/192373). You can obtain this Java object in your C++ code [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436260/192373), but this still needs **JNIEnv**.

If you really really want to extract an asset from your APK with no JNI  interaction, it not impossible. The trick is to [find your APK file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7701801/192373) and trust that it is a ZIP file under the hood.

Comment: @RahulNaik It sounds like this worked for you, if it did please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone share a simple example on how to read the data from a raw file and how to access it(Like showing it in logcat)?

[Here](https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-config-provider) example project that unpacks resource file from res/raw and puts it to FilesDir location (e.g. /data/user/0/com.example.myapp/files) which is accessible from native code.

Also [there](https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-config-provider/blob/master/doc/activity-diagram.png) an activity diagram that describes the algorithm for this approach.