# How can I open binary file from c++ function in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have a file on path `app/src/main/res/networks/net.dlc` which Im trying to read from c++ function which is called from Java:

```
void someCppFunc()
{
    static std::string dlc = "net.dlc";
    std::ifstream dlcFile(dlc);
}
```

But its always `nullptr` when I run this code on my phone. How do I read this file? I tried different paths, `app/src/main/res/networks/net.dlc`, `res/networks/net.dlc`, nothing works. I do not understand Android Studio app packaging system and where to look for my files once app is on the phone, any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The paths ,out mention are inside Android Studio before compiling the app. If you want to access the file at runtime you have to use the path inside the APK so get the compiled APK and decompile it to see where you file is located.  But the correct way would be to include the file as asset and then use NDK asset API https://stackoverflow.com/q/49322783/150978